# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' - root account requires PW reset every time after re-booting (Windows 7 SP1)

Tags: mysql, sql, root

I can connect to mysql database without issue after resetting the root password:

`C:\\> C:\mysql\bin\mysqld-nt --init-file=C:\\\\mysql-init.txt`

where `mysql-init.txt` contains:

`UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('MyNewPass') WHERE User='root'; 
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

However, every time I reboot windows, I get this error message when I try to connect to the database:

`C:\\>mysql -u root -p 
Enter Password: ******** 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

I have also tried without a password, same failure.

It doesn't seem like a good practice to reset the root password every time I reboot. Is this a known issue with a known fix?

Comment: This belongs on [dba.se] as it is about database configuration, not programming.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is , like following.

Log on to your system as Administrator.

Stop the MySQL server if it is running. For a server that is running as a Windows service, go to the Services manager: From the Start menu, select Control Panel, then Administrative Tools, then Services. Find the MySQL service in the list and stop it.

If your server is not running as a service, you may need to use the Task Manager to force it to stop.

Create a text file containing the following statements. Replace the password with the password that you want to use.

`UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('MyNewPass') WHERE User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`
Write the UPDATE and FLUSH statements each on a single line. The UPDATE statement resets the password for all root accounts, and the FLUSH statement tells the server to reload the grant tables into memory so that it notices the password change.

Save the file. For this example, the file will be named `C:\mysql-init.txt`.

Open a console window to get to the command prompt: From the Start menu, select Run, then enter cmd as the command to be run.

Start the MySQL server with the special `--init-file` option (notice that the backslash in the option value is doubled):

`C:\> C:\mysql\bin\mysqld-nt --init-file=C:\\mysql-init.txt`
If you installed MySQL to a location other than C:\mysql, adjust the command accordingly.

The server executes the contents of the file named by the `--init-file` option at startup, changing each root account password.

You can also add the `--console` option to the command if you want server output to appear in the console window rather than in a log file.

If you installed MySQL using the MySQL Installation Wizard, you may need to specify a --defaults-file option:

`C:\> "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin\mysqld-nt.exe"
         --defaults-file="C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.0\\my.ini"
         --init-file=C:\\mysql-init.txt`
The appropriate --defaults-file setting can be found using the Services Manager: From the Start menu, select Control Panel, then Administrative Tools, then Services. Find the MySQL service in the list, right-click it, and choose the Properties option. The Path to executable field contains the --defaults-file setting.

After the server has started successfully, delete `C:\mysql-init.txt`.